# Set image source to grid template field WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to set image source to template field in wpf grid. Its a delete column. My code is as follows

```
<my:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="258" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,18" Name="grd_list" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="430">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden" Header="f1" Binding="{Binding f1}"/>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="f2" Binding="{Binding f2}"/>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="f3" Binding="{Binding f3}"/>
            <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding active}"/>
            <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="f4" Binding="{Binding f4}"/>
            <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding createDate}"/>
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="btn_edt" ToolTip="Edit the row"  CommandParameter="{Binding f1}" Click="btn_edt_Click">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Images/imgs/edit.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
```

I want to set image to    like

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Name="btn_edt" ToolTip="Edit the row"  CommandParameter="{Binding f1}" Click="btn_edt_Click">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Images/imgs/edit.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If that possible, how can I do that?

 Thanks in advance
Sivajith

Comment: Your code seems correct, just try to use correct path of your image : 
"/YourAssemblyName;component/Images/imgs/edit.png"

Comment: it works for edit field. I am asking about delete field <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" CellTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>. for this?

Comment: I don't know if i can understand your issue correctly, but it's the same strcture and the same code, you have to do copy paste from your edit template. then just update the image path and the command that does that.

Comment: can you please post {StaticResource myTemplate} too.. So we will get idea about your issue??

Comment: What error are you getting? were is your StaticResource Code?